# Error of prediction from linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, predictive-models, error

I have an equation:

$$
\large
y = 0.243x + 0.145 
$$

In the form:

$$
\Large
y = ax + b
$$

I use it to predict $y$ when $x = 2$. To estimate the distribution around $\hat{y} = 0.631$ I need an estimate of uncertainty. This I am calculating using the following formula:

$$
\large
\Delta y = \sqrt{(a \cdot \Delta x)^2 + (\Delta a \cdot x)^2 + (\Delta b)^2}
$$

Is this correct? Is there a package in R that will calculate this? Primarily out of interest, as I was digging around and could not find anything.

Comment: Hi @Aaron Simmons, welcome to CV. How did you come up with $y = 0.243.x + 0.145$? Did you use a linear model e.g. `lm` in R? If so, you can use the `predict` function with `interval` argument to come up with the uncertainty (either confidence interval for the mean, or prediction interval for the realised value). See `?predict.lm`

Comment: @AlexJ Thanks for the response. Yes, in R. The issue I have been having is aligning the estimate of uncertainty derived from the interval = prediction argument in the predict function with the value when I calculate delta-y using the equation above. This demonstrates to me that I am calculating the uncertainty based on the interval argument incorrectly. Need to go back to that.

Comment: Where did you get the $\Delta y$ equation from? What is it supposed to be doing? What do the values in the equation mean?

Comment: Your calculation $\Delta y$ is not correct: it's for a completely different situation (where $a,$ $b,$ and $x$ are all random variables, they are independent, and certain technical assumptions about their distributions pertain; here, $x$ is not random and $a$ and $b$ will not be independent unless $x$ and $y$ are centered variables).  For correct formulas, please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=formula+prediction+interval+regression).

Comment: @AlexJ The equation came from a professor of chemical engineering. The background behind this is that I am writing a standard for an agricultural sector to conservatively estimate the GHG emissions reductions associated with the implementation of a technology. It is generic guidance, my equation is an example and in reality the equation could relate to anything and the variables could be just about anything to do with GHG emissions in an ag system. Uncertainty around the prediction allows for estimation of a prob of exceedance. That is the short of it.

Answer (score 2):

[Faraway, "Practical Regression and Anova using R" (2002)](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf) gives the formula in section 3.5 on p. 39. I personally do not like calling this "Confidence intervals for predictions" and would rather call it "prediction intervals" - [there is a difference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info).

In R, if you have fitted your model using `lm()`, then you can get prediction intervals directly by using `predict.lm()` with the `interval="prediction"` parameter.

Comment: This answer needs a *lot* of clarification and explanation of its meaning and scope of application, because the formula simply is not a standard least squares prediction interval (or even a standard error of prediction).